# Spring: Cannot find resources

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-mvc, resources

I'm very new to Spring and I cannot access to my resources. I use Spring + Thymeleaf and my directionary structure is:

```
src
  - main
    - java
      - Application.java
      - controller
        - LanchController.java
      - ...
    - resources
      - css
        - test.css
      - templates
        - account.html
      - ...
```

The application is loading correctly but the html templates don't find the css, etc. 
account.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/test.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello, User!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I already tried many paths like `../css/...` or `/resources/css/..` but nothing works. I hope someone can help me. I have followed this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Greetings 
Chryb

Comment: is the view resolver set in the WebConfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example here:
http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/04/how-to-spring-boot-and-thymeleaf-with-maven.html

Looks like you need to add a Thymeleaf attribute to the link:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Spring Boot!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link href="../static/css/core.css"
          th:href="@{/css/core.css}"
          rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello Spring Boot!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now, the problem is that the build gives an error and says: `Cannot find template location: class path resource [templates/] (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)` Where should  I add this location?

Answer (score -2):

Please see my example in https://github.com/webcompere/SpringHelloWorld  You need to declare resource folders in your spring context.

In my example, my Spring dispatcher is declared in its own spring beans file - https://github.com/webcompere/SpringHelloWorld/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

The lines:

```
<mvc:resources mapping ="/css/**" location ="/WEB-INF/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping ="/js/**" location ="/WEB-INF/js/" />
<mvc:resources mapping ="/images/**" location ="/WEB-INF/images/" />
<mvc:resources mapping ="/*. html" location ="/WEB-INF/" />
```

are how the dispatcher is happy to serve these resources. The reason I need this is because I've told the application to respond to everything by routing through spring, owing to this in the web.xml

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: What do you mean? The `web.xml` file?

Comment: Please see the edit to this post - more detail provided.